# Confusion about Laravel cache with file storage system and its security

Tags: caching, laravel

I have two questions about laravel cache.

1. I'm in a confusion that we know that every user has different session, so there is no chance that ones session data will replace or mess with others, but is laravel cache with file storage system is same like session? I mean is cache variable and its value is different for every user like session? or it will be a shared variable and the value will replaced by other users?
2. Is it secured to store sensitive data to cache with file storage system? because we know that we have to give write permission to the storage folder. and I think laravel do not encrypt cached value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You mix cache up with session..They are just two things.Cache is just a key-value data structure.All users get the same value with the same key.This has nothing to do with file storage system or whatever.It's just how cache works.If you want to cache personal information for each user,use a key like 'user:1' or whatever.

2.No.No matter which driver you choose,Laravel just stores serialized strings without encryption.You have to do it by your self.